# Unexpected and cryptic dotnet run "fail" messages with Webpack with HardSource on Vue.js site

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, webpack-plugin

When I start my Vue.js .NET Core project using `dotnet run`, I get the following "fail" messages, but the site seems to work fine.  Anyone have an idea why I am getthing these messages and how to troubleshoot it?

```
c:\myproj\Web>dotnet run
Using launch settings from c:\myproj\Web\Properties\launchSettings.json...
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: c:\myproj\Web
Now listening on: http://localhost:60000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      [hardsource:be1e46f8] Using 230 MB of disk space.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      [hardsource:be1e46f8] Tracking node dependencies with: package-lock.json.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      [hardsource:be1e46f8] Reading from cache be1e46f8...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like dotnet run reports the Hardsource verbose messages as FAILs when they are not.  I just modified my HardSource config as follows (in webpack.config.*.js) and the messages went away.

```
new HardSourceWebpackPlugin({ info: { mode: 'none', level: 'warn' } }),
```